# Is the left shift $y\mapsto x+y$ measurable on $E^{[0,\:\infty)}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $$\sigma_x:E\to E\;,\;\;\;y\mapsto x+y$$ for $x\in E$ and $$\tilde\sigma_x:E^{[0,\:\infty)}\to E^{[0,\:\infty)}\;,\;\;\;y\mapsto x+y$$ for $x\in E^{[0,\:\infty)}$.

> Let $x\in E^{[0,\:\infty)}$. How can we show that $\tilde\sigma_x$ is $\left(\mathcal B(E)^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)},\mathcal B(E)^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}\right)$-measurable?

$\sigma_y$ is clearly $(\mathcal B(E),\mathcal B(E))$-measurable for all $y\in E$. Let $\pi_I$ denote the projection of $E^{[0,\:\infty)}$ onto $E^I$ for nonempty $I\subseteq[0,\infty)$ and $\pi_t:=\pi_{\{t\}}$ for $t\ge0$. By definition, $$\mathcal B(E)^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}=\sigma(\pi_t,t\ge0)\tag1.$$ Moreover, this $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the system $$\mathcal Z:=\left\{\pi_{\{t_1,\:\ldots\:,\:t_n\}}^{-1}(B_1\times\cdots\times B_n):n\in\mathbb N\text{ and }B_1,\ldots,B_n\in\mathcal B(E)\right\}.$$ So, it's sufficient to show $$\tilde\sigma_x^{-1}\left(\pi_{\{t_1,\:\ldots\:,\:t_n\}}^{-1}(B_1\times\cdots\times B_n)\right)\in\mathcal B(E)^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}\tag2.$$ How do we do that?

Clearly, $(2)$ is equal to $$\left\{y\in E^{[0,\:\infty)}:y(t_i)\in\sigma_{x(t_i)}^{-1}(B_i)\text{ for all }1\le i\le n\right\}\tag3$$ and, as mentioned before, $\sigma_{x(t_i)}^{-1}(B_i)\in\mathcal B(E)$. How can we conclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an easy consequence of the definition of product sigma algebra (product sigma algebra is the smallest sigma algebra that makes all projections measurable) that a map from a measure space to a product space with the product sigma algebra is measurable if and only if each of it's components is measurable. So we need to show that for each $t \in [0, \infty)$, the function $f \colon E^{[0, \infty)} \to E$ defined by $f(y) = x_t + y_t$ is measurable. Let $A \in B(E)$. We have $f^{-1}(A) = \{y \in E : y_t \in \sigma_{x_t}^{-1}(A)\} = \pi_t^{-1}(\sigma_{x_t}^{-1}(A))$ is measurable by definition of product measure since $\sigma_{x_t}$ is measurable.